# How to use symfony, twig, and doctrine in a controller inside an existing project

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

I have been using the SymfonyCast on Symfony 4 to try and help me to connect the pieces. I have learned a lot about doctrine Symfony and twig and the environment that they are supposed to work together in. However, that is not what I have to build on. I need to build inside an existing project OpenEMR.

I posted my project code here:

https://github.com/juggernautsei/symfony_twig_doctrine_component/blob/master/library/financialreports/src/FinancialSummaryByInsuranceController.php

The controller works to load the twig template. Now, I am trying to populate the controller with data from the database. I have built the entity class and the repository class. I just can't figure out what to put in this line.

```
     public function getpaidata($insurerid)
      {
         $payments = $this->repository
     }
```

To access the class in the repository. The IDE suggested the code in the repository class.

```
public function getInsurerPaid(ArSession $insurerId)
{
    /*$insurerPaid = $this->_em->getRepository($this->_entityName)->findBy([
        "payer_id" => $insurerId
    ]);*/
    $insurerPaid = $this->findBy([
        'payer_id' => $insurerId
    ]);
    return $insurerPaid;
}
```

But as I am typing in out the code in the controller, the IDE PHPStorm is not suggesting anything. So, I am stuck. I have tried the suggested code here

https://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/doctrine.html#creating-an-entity-class
https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony-doctrine/repository

but nothing tells me how to access the method that is in the repository class.

**UPDATE:**

The getpaiddata() method is now changed to

```
/**
 * @return Fully hydrated object.
 */
public function getpaidata($insurerid)
{
    $row = $this->repository->findBy([
        "payer_id" => $insurerid
    ]);

    return $row;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is likely how you get `$this->repository`. If you fetch it via the entity manager, via `$this->_em->getRepository($entityName)` like in the commented snippet, the return value has a type hint which tells the IDE that it is just a generic EntityRepository instead of your custom repository class.

You can install the Symfony-plugin to PhpStorm, which will give you better autocompletion if your entity has the right annotation `@Entity(repositoryClass="...")`.

In a typical Symfony 4 application you could also just inject the correct repository, instead of the EntityManager, e.g. in your constructor:

```php
public function __construct(PaidDataRepository $repository)
{
    $this->repository = $repository;
}
```

From what it looks like, OpenEMR has it's own way of creating the EntityManager using `Connector::instance()`. So this will probably not work for you easily, unfortunately.

Another way around this would be to just place a type hint above assigning your variable:

```php
/** @var App\Repository\PaidDataRepository $repository */
$repository = $this->_em->getRepository(PaidData::class)
```

or, since you have a class variable you can put a similar annotation on there.

Comment: This was not a direct fix to my issue but I will post the solution on git. I was overthinking it and it was really simple. On to the next issue in the build process.

Comment: @user1794918 just an FYI, your code will likely not work. `getpaiddate()` does not return anything, so `$list` will always be `null` here: https://github.com/juggernautsei/symfony_twig_doctrine_component/blob/master/library/financialreports/src/FinancialSummaryByInsuranceController.php#L51. It's no big issue right now, because it's not used (yet), but might be problematic later. I am not sure if this is, because the code is unfinished due to the problem, but thought I mention it to save you some time debugging.